# how to call a function from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I cant able to call the functions when I link it through different javascript file
I wanna call this to my HTML  how should I do this I tried adding script file but it doesn't work

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jj.js"></script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" id="showSlides()">
      <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
        <img src="img1.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
        <img src="img2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
        <img src="img3.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="dotcontainer">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <body>
<head>
```

now this is my .js file

```
function showSlides() {

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slideIndex++;

  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

Comment: call your showSlides() function on page load event i.e <body onload="showSlides()">

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you actually try to call the function?

Comment: yeah but when i write that in html it works but i cut paste in javascript and add it through src it doesnt work

Comment: ultimate developer how can i do that just by linking the .js file

Comment: May be your script will not be referred properly. Try like this <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jj.js"></script>

Comment: Can you post your complete HTML code?

Comment: @harindersingh check my answer

Comment: but why in body only can you explain please and what if i have other function do i need to call in body only @the_ultimate_developer

Comment: "when i write that in html it works but i cut paste in javascript and add it through src it doesnt work" ...this makes no sense...just moving the function code to a separate file will not change the fact that you never actually call the function.

Comment: However, now I formatted your code properly, I can see you have 1) a `</script>` with no parent - so remove that. 2) a second `<body>` but no `</body>`, and 3) a second `<head>` which I assume was meant to be `</html>`. These are basic HTML issues - please check your work more carefully!

Comment: And `id="showSlides()"` makes no sense. This looks like a function call, yet it's inside the `id` attribute. You can't call a function from within an attribute definition, unless that attribute is the name of an event e.g. onclick or something. I suggest you maybe take a little time to brush up your HTML and JS knowledge in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <html>
      <head>
          <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body onload="showSlides()">

          <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
              <img src="img1.png" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
              <img src="img2.png" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="image-sliderfade fade">
              <img src="img3.png" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="dotcontainer">
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
         </div>



         </div>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function showSlides() { var i;

    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");

    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }


    slideIndex++;


    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";


    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the script tag at the bottom of the body. That should work.

Comment: i dont wanna add the function in html file only i wanna call it from outside

Comment: You need to load the js file at the bottom of the body <script type="application/javascript" src="jj.js"></script> and call the function <body onload="showSlides()">

Comment: @harindersingh What do you mean by ' call it from outside' ?

Comment: means i dont want to add script in html it should be stored in .js file and working through there

Comment: @harindersingh the important point in this answer is the `<body onload="showSlides()">` - this is how you ensure the function runs when the page is loaded. All you have to do after that is make sure `<script type="application/javascript" src="jj.js"></script> ` is added in your "head" section, so that the script is ready before the onload function runs. You're correct that you don't need the inline script within the HTML, in the way it's been shown here. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915934/5947043) actually gives you a clearer example, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You've included the file. However you never execute the function all your code is in.
This is likely the cause.

Try the following:
on line 1 of `jj.js` (before the function) write `console.log('this is jj.js');` and run the page. In your console (web inspector) you should see the message "this is jj.js" which means the script tag is doing it's thing.

Then remove the console log (you don't need it) and either make sure your code isn't inside the function (so simply remove it) or invoke the function by doing something like:

`showSlides(); function showSlides() { console.log('Init function')}`

Comment: "the style tag" ...I assume you mean script tag? But a better way to check whether the script file has loaded is simply to check the Network tab and ensure it doesn't 404 or anything on that file. Of course the console can also be used to check for syntax errors etc, but you don't need an explicit console.log really just to verify that the script file was loaded.

Comment: Absolutely right about the tag, got distracted while typing. I'll adjust it accordingly. It's true that nowadays console.log isn't the simplest / recommended way anymore. However it was a valid method for many years that should not be forgotten i.m.o.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your second code-snippet to also execute the funtion when the page is loaded, like:

```
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="application/javascript" src="jj.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        showSlides();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a self executing function like this :

```
(function() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
         dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);

})();
```

I did not test your function if it works, I only copy and paste it in my answer.
If you are using jQuery then you can call it when the document is loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    Your function call here.....

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="application/javascript" src="jj.js"></script>
```

You can use either jQuery or pure javascript for this i.e

```
// use dom elements
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        showSlides()
    }, false);   
   </script>
```

> DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
 // use below function
     <script>
    (function () {
        showSlides()
     })();
     </script>
```

> It’s an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression. It executes immediately after it’s creation.

```
 // jQuery function
    <script>
    $(function() {
        showSlides()
    });
    </script>

// use window event
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    showSlides()
};
</script>
```

> it is fired when the entire page loads, including its content (images, CSS, scripts, etc.)

```
    <script>   
    $(document).ready( function () {
        showSlides()
    })
  </script>
```

> It is fired when the DOM is ready which can be prior to images and other external content is loaded.

Add one of above function in your jj script

Comment: it's nice to show the two different approaches, but clear, _separate_ examples of each would be helpful. To the uninitiated it would be unclear which bits of the code above is required in each circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your reference to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jj.js"></script>
```

Call your `showSlides()` inside anywhere your script `jj.js`.
e.g

```
function showSlides(){
   //Function body goes here
}

showSlides();
```

But best is to call it `onload` either javascript's `window.onload` or jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){ showSlides()})`